# Custom hashcode/equals operation for HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode, overriding

Is there a an implementation of the HashMap class (or Map interface) that will allow me to use alternate hashcode and equals operations...
Similar to how collections of the same type can be sorted in multiple ways using the Comparator in Collections.sort(list, comparator).

I would like to avoid if possible, creating a key wrapper providing the desired hashcode and equals operations.

---

In my case, one of the scenarios why I need something like this:

In my web application, for each request, I load the Location/ISP and other data.
In different parts of code (in my service and repository layers) I have "minimized" caches specific to its requirement.

Here is a simplified code example:

```
class GeoIpData{
    private String countryName;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String isp;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //countryName hashCode
        //state hashCode
        //city hashCode
        //isp hashCode
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // compare countryName
        // compare state
        // compare city
        // compare isp
    }
}

 Map<GeoIpData,#Type1> fullCache = ... //This cache needs to be unique per countryName,state,city and isp
 Map<GeoIpData,#Type2> countryCache = ... //This cache needs to be unique per countryName
 Map<GeoIpData,#Type2> ispCache = ... //This cache needs to be unique per countryName,isp
```

To achieve this the above 3 maps need 3 different hashcode and equals methods.

```
fullCache:
hashCode -> GeoIpData.hashCode();
equals   -> GeoIpData.equals(Object obj);

countryCache:
hashCode -> {countryName hashCode }
equals   -> {compare countryName }

ispCache:
hashCode -> {countryName hashCode & isp hashCode }
equals   -> {compare countryName & compare isp hashCode }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GNU Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) allows you to provide specific TObjectHashingStrategy  with your own hash and equals functions for TCustomHashMap.

Comment: Hi "Noofz"
Thanks for the advise, let me do some benchmarks first...
Have you used this before, if you have, how does it work in multi-threaded environments?

The cache.get(...) operation gets performed 5,000 to 30,000 times per second and can spike to over double that.

Comment: No, nforunately I dont have experience of using it under such a great preasure.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've got the same requirement - I've been using wrapper objects to achieve it, but I need to reduce the memory occupied by a very large map, and the wrapper objects are a significant overhead. So I guess the question for me is whether the GNU Trove map implementation is space-efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Initial Java API bounded `equals` / `hashCode` behavior to type (class) because they didn't have lambdas back those days.

In order to reuse existing API / implementations - make ephemeral keys:

```
public CountryKey {
    private String country;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof CountryKey)) { return false; }
        CountryKey that = (CountryKey) obj;
        return this.country.equals(that.country);
    }
    @Override int hashCode() {
         return country.hashCode();
    }
}
```

or wrappers:

```
public CountryKey {
    private GeoIpData holder;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof CountryKey)) { return false; }
        CountryKey that = (CountryKey) obj;
        return this.holder.getCountry().equals(that.holder.getCountry());
    }
    @Override int hashCode() {
         return holder.getCountry().hashCode();
    }
}
```

and write helper constructors for keys:

```
public class GeoIpData {
     public CountryKey buildCountryKey() {
          return new CountryKey(this.country);
     }
}
```

Comment: Trove worked perfectly - even under higher load that I mensioned.
However, more than 7 years on, I agree with you, I would have simply created key wrappers.

Comment: Ephemeral keys only make sense if they encapsulate more than one property. If you need one property, you can use the property value as key in the first place, e.g. use the country `String` as key instead of wrapping it in a `CountryKey` object. With recent Java versions, you can use `record` classes to implement the multi-property keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of non-concurrent third party hash maps, some of which support custom equals and hashCode, like the one mentioned in Mikhail's answer. I know of no concurrent implementation though.

**Here's somewhat of a hack that allows you to use the standard ConcurrentHashMap with custom equals/hashCode implementations. It uses a thread local variable to convey which equals/hashCode implementation keys should use at any given point in time.**

First a decorator to add the functionality to any `ConcurrentMap` implementation:

```java
public class CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator<K, V>
        implements ConcurrentMap<K, V> {

    public interface EqualsAndHashCode<X> {
        boolean equals(X x, X y);
        int hashCode(X x);
    }
    private final ConcurrentMap<K, V> decoratee;
    private final EqualsAndHashCode<K> equalsAndHashCode;
    private final Consumer<EqualsAndHashCode<K>> equalsAndHashCodeSetter;

    public CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator(ConcurrentMap<K, V> decoratee, EqualsAndHashCode<K> equalsAndHashCode, Consumer<EqualsAndHashCode<K>> equalsAndHashCodeSetter) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.equalsAndHashCode = equalsAndHashCode;
        this.equalsAndHashCodeSetter = equalsAndHashCodeSetter;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        equalsAndHashCodeSetter.accept(equalsAndHashCode);
        final V ret = decoratee.get(key);
        equalsAndHashCodeSetter.accept(null);
        return ret;
    }

    public Set<K> keySet() {
// Note that this is potentially dangerous, as the caller will have to make sure
// equalsAndHashCodeSetter.accept() is called before/after calling some of the methods of the returned set
        return decoratee.keySet();
    }

    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
// Note that this is potentially dangerous, as the caller will have to make sure
// equalsAndHashCodeSetter.accept() is called before/after calling some of the methods of the returned set
        return decoratee.entrySet();
    }

    // omitting the other methods, most of which need to be
    // wrapped in equalsAndHashCodeSetter.accept() calls as well
}
```

Here's an example on how to use the same key object instances a) with the default equals/hashCode, and b) with a custom one:

```java
class CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecoratorTest {

    private static abstract class DynamicEqualsAndHashCodeObject<K> {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        private static final ThreadLocal<CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode> equalsAndHashCode = new ThreadLocal<>();

        static void setEqualsAndHashCode(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode equalsAndHashCode) {
            DynamicEqualsAndHashCodeObject.equalsAndHashCode.set(equalsAndHashCode);
        }

        private CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode<K> getComparator() {
            //noinspection rawtypes
            final CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode raw = DynamicEqualsAndHashCodeObject.equalsAndHashCode.get();
            //noinspection unchecked
            return raw == null ? null : (CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode<K>) DynamicEqualsAndHashCodeObject.equalsAndHashCode.get();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            var equalsAndHashCode = getComparator();
            //noinspection unchecked
            return equalsAndHashCode != null ? equalsAndHashCode.equals(dis(), (K) obj) : super.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            var equalsAndHashCode = getComparator();
            return equalsAndHashCode != null ? equalsAndHashCode.hashCode(dis()) : super.hashCode();
        }

        abstract K dis();
    }

    static class Key extends DynamicEqualsAndHashCodeObject<Key> {
        final String a;
        final String b;

        public Key(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return a + b;
        }

        @Override
        Key dis() {
            return this;
        }

        static class AEqualsAndHashCode implements CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator.EqualsAndHashCode<Key> {
            public boolean equals(Key x, Key y) {return Objects.equals(x.a, y.a);}
            public int hashCode(Key key) {return Objects.hashCode(key.a);}
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        var key11 = new Key("1", "1");
        var key12 = new Key("1", "2");
        var key21 = new Key("2", "1");
        var key22 = new Key("2", "2");
        var mapDefault = new ConcurrentHashMap<Key, String>();
        mapDefault.put(key11, key11.toString());
        mapDefault.put(key12, key12.toString());
        mapDefault.put(key21, key21.toString());
        mapDefault.put(key22, key22.toString());
        mapDefault.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("mapDefault: " + k + " -> " + v));
        var mapA = new CustomEqualsAndHashCodeConcurrentMapDecorator<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<Key, String>(), new Key.AEqualsAndHashCode(), Key::setEqualsAndHashCode);
        mapA.put(key11, key11.toString());
        mapA.put(key12, key12.toString());
        mapA.put(key21, key21.toString());
        mapA.put(key22, key22.toString());
        mapA.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("mapA: " + k + " -> " + v));
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
mapDefault: 12 -> 12
mapDefault: 11 -> 11
mapDefault: 21 -> 21
mapDefault: 22 -> 22
mapA: 11 -> 12
mapA: 21 -> 22
```